# Usage of d’accord?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, vocabulaire, usage

When using the word d’accord, can it be used in the context of wellness or is it more so only usable in the context of agreement? I.e. would Je suis d’accord be interpreted as “I am okay” or “I agree”?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*D'accord* is only used in an agreement context, i.e.:

> *je suis d'accord*

implies

> *je suis d'accord avec quelqu'un ou avec une suggestion, une idée, etc.*

Meaning "I agree with someone/some idea..."

To translate "I'm okay" in the context of wellness, you might say:

> *Je vais bien*

or

> *Je n'ai rien*

Comment: Alright, so what word can I use in context of wellness?